# Entity Framework 6 - update entity value during loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, mapping

I have a table in SQL Server which has encrypted data in one column. But not for all rows, there is a complex logic in the background.

On the other side, I have a web app which uses Entity Framework 6 for data access. When I need save data I override method

```
public override int SaveChanges()
```

in my `DbContext`.

Here I can encrypt data before saving to database. This works well.

But now I need to decrypt data when being loaded from the database, before mapping. I thought I can override

```
public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
```

method in the `DbContext` where I use same logic. But it seems this method is called **after** mapping so changes has no effect (I can not see them in UI).

Is there any way how to set this logic for specific entity type in one place for whole app?

Comment: Make it part of the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I already did the same thing you want to do
by adding a new property to my model
like this :

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
public String UserName { set; get; } 

[NotMapped]
public string DecryptedUserName
{
    get { return Decrypt(UserName); } 
}
```

Please let me know if you try this

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what am I looking for. I need to catch db loading for specific entity type and modify data on this entity depending on the logic before they are send to controller.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using `DbCommandInterceptor`. Here I can override `ReaderExecuted` method where I can modify data in database context. This changes are propagated to application.